# How to change margin in Binance API Python

Tags: python, json, binance, binance-api-client

How can I define the type of margin (isolated or cross) in my code ///

Also, how can I determine the amount of leverage?

I read here but didn't understand anything

https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#change-margin-type-trade

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

- The endpoint to change to initial leverage: `POST /fapi/v1/leverage`
- The endpoint to change the margin type ( isolated or cross-margin): `POST /fapi/v1/marginType`